# Websocket server cannot close connection with a client when nginx is used as proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, proxy, websocket

Nginx is sitting between websocket clients and a websocket server. When the server issues websocket close for a particular client, the connection is closed between the server and nginx but nginx does not close connection with the client. And client will keep the connection open while I want the connection to close immediately. What is likely wrong? Is there some nginx configuration that I am missing. Nginx is used here primarily for decrypting SSL.

Comment: Please post your configuration.